# Application to display 3D model of the molecules in android

Tags: android, android-image

I need to develop an application that displays the 3D model of the molecules in android. Can anybody tell me how this can be achieved.

Thanks in advance.

Sundeep

Comment: It can be achieved by you putting some effort into your own problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it should be achieved as usually all 3d graphics achieved - via OpenGL (android has support for OpenGL ES). You could start from [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) and proceed further with some of many OpenGL books.

Comment: Thanks. I need to know how a molecular formula can be represented as a 3D model. I had read in an article that there is some CML(Chemical Markup Language) to achieve this. Can you please tell me how this can be used to solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I've never faced similar challenge on opengl. I would suggest to open another question with e.g. opengl tags, because I thought that the question is about 'how to make 3d thing like molecular formula', but not how exactly implement it. Same time I'm about 100% sure that it could be achieved on android with opengl, molecular theory knowledge and some coding (probably, 'lot of' opengl coding or usage of some 3rd party libraries ported to android).